# Bluetooth driver not working

Tags: drivers, 18.04, bluetooth, realtek-wireless

### Problem

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.4 on my HP Notebook - 14-cf0013dx, and I have had to manually install a driver for WiFi and Bluetooth before.

When I try enabling Bluetooth, [this](https://streamable.com/skcfe) happens.

My first thought was that this was a GUI bug, so I attempted to connect my Bluetooth device using the 'bluetoothctl' command on terminal. When I run bluetoothctl to list the controllers, nothing comes out. When I try to pair, I get a message that says 'No default controller available.'

Any help and feedback is appreciated. Thank you!

#### Command Outputs

```
sudo service bluetooth status

● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-03-26 17:08:35 CDT; 6min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 1066 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─1066 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Mar 26 17:08:34 laptop systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Mar 26 17:08:34 laptop bluetoothd[1066]: Bluetooth daemon 5.48
Mar 26 17:08:35 laptop bluetoothd[1066]: Starting SDP server
Mar 26 17:08:35 laptop systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Mar 26 17:08:36 laptop bluetoothd[1066]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
Mar 26 17:08:36 laptop bluetoothd[1066]: No Bluetooth address for index 0
```

```
rfkill list

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

```
lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Intel(R) 100 Series Chipset Family LPC Controller/eSPI Controller - 9D4E (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device d723
```

```
hciconfig -a

hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00  ACL MTU: 0:0  SCO MTU: 0:0
    DOWN 
    RX bytes:0 acl:0 sco:0 events:0 errors:0
    TX bytes:0 acl:0 sco:0 commands:1 errors:1
    Features: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
    Packet type: DM1 DH1 HV1 
    Link policy: 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT
```

```
hcitool dev

Devices:
```

```
sudo netstat -anp | grep bluetooth

unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     23417    1066/bluetoothd      
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     24889    1066/bluetoothd      
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    24885    1066/bluetoothd
```

```
lsusb

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:b009 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04ca:7092 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
dmesg | grep Bluetooth

[   18.640104] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   18.640116] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   18.640118] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   18.640120] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   18.640123] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   21.824065] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1001 tx timeout
[   29.916167] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI_OP_READ_LOCAL_VERSION failed (-110)
[   34.774400] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   34.774400] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   34.774402] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

Comment: Looks like Canonical's a little behind the times, as https://certification.ubuntu.com/catalog/component/0bda:b009 does not show your model of lappie when I searched on the Bluetooth device identifier _0bda:b009_